# TEXTFILE generated by Athena is empty

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I used the below SQL query to create a table in Athena.The records are  present in a csv file in the location specified in LOCATION in the code.I could succesfully create the table and view the expected table in the results in Athena.But if I go to S3 bucket where the table is stored as TEXTFILE and open the file, it is empty.Can I know the reason?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS range (
  group_id string,
  start_value int,
  end_value int
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://varun/test/';
```

Comment: did you insert data in table?

Comment: yes i have inserted the data.The code fetches the data from csv file located at "s3://varun/test/" and creates the table.I can view the data in the table in the results section in Athena.But the generated Textfile in S3 bucket is empty.

Comment: try `describe extended <your_database>.<your_table>;` it shows you information about table and there is a path, where data stored ("location" field).

Comment: @VarunKumar are you talking about the `output s3` files `empty`?

Comment: @RedBoy Yes the output s3 textfile generated is empty .